# SQL (Microsoft) - 2 updates at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
create table lastnum
(
 id int,
 num int
)
```

It has one row

```
Id    num

1     101
```

2 users perform the same stored procedure at the same time - the stored procedure is

```
declare @num int

set @num = (select num + 1 from lastnum where id = 1)

update lastnum
set num = @num
where Id = 1

return @num
```

What is the likely hood of the command running at the exact microsecond so even after both calls, the value of num is only 102

Comment: What is the likelihood?   How could anyone possibly know this?

Comment: Read about transactions.

Comment: Do you expect someone to tell you "this will happen 42% of the time"? Anything above exactly 0% is unacceptable if that count is important.

Comment: To answer the posters - maybe the question should be "Will it ever happen?" If the answer is yes, then please suggest how to do it.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, what you're looking for here is a SEQUENCE object.

Comment: The procedure is on stand alone system? If not this "likely hood" you mentioned is seriously increased. Lock tables or just Sequence

Comment: This depends heavily on the data within that table (how many records exist within it will determine how fast that query runs).  Either way, as others have suggested, there's much safer ways to do this sort of thing.  Going this route is at best bad practice, at worst, jeopardizing the integrity of your data.

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible for that code to "fail" and provide the same number to two users.

Whether this is actually likely to happen in your environment depends on your load (if this code runs only rarely, you might get away with it) and how your server is configured. Sql Server has different [Isolation Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx) you can use to determine what degree of potential conflict is allowed. At the highest isolation, that code is completely safe (assuming your users are getting an implicit transaction)... but the performance penalty is potentially severe.

Sql Server has built-in mechanisms you should use to avoid these potential conflicts: namely `identity` columns and the `scope_identity()` function. Newer versions of Sql Server also have **[Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql).**

[Locking hints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172398(v=sql.110).aspx) or an explicit transaction might also help you... but I would try to avoid these in favor of the other options in this answer.

Comment: There's also the `output` clause which can be used in conjunction with `identity` columns (may be a more viable option if sequences aren't a thing in the poster's environment).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the "likely hood" of it happening is, but it is definitely **possible**, this is because there is no transaction around the line where you calculate the new value and the line where you update the value.

Answer (score 0):

output clause may do what you need

```
declare @t table (id int primary key, num int);
insert into @t values (1, 101);
declare @n table (num int);
update @t 
set num = num+1 
output inserted.num into @n
where id = 1;
select num from @n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eric Brandt and Joel Coehoorn

The solution was to use 'sequences' - something new in SQL 2012 onwards I think